# Camel Context - The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Tags: java, spring-boot, circular-dependency, spring-camel

I'm working with Spring Boot with build.gradle file, does anyone know how to fix this error below?

Sorry I'm very new to SpringBoot and Java.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

template
???????
|  epolicy-camel-context
?     ?
|  org.apache.camel.impl.health.DefaultHealthCheckRegistry
???????

Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

this is my camel-context version from build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-core', version: '3.2.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring', version: '3.20.3'
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-stream', version: '3.20.3'
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-jms', version: '3.20.3'
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring-xml', version: '3.20.3'
```